# Displaying Array in NSLog

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have made a basic card shuffling algorithm.

I want to check if its working through the nslog.

It crashes the app and puts in a break point at the nslog

Can someone help with doing so?

```
-(IBAction)suffle:(id)sender
{
    NSMutableArray *arrayExample = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [arrayExample addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
    [arrayExample addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]];
    [arrayExample addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3]];
    [arrayExample addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:4]];

    for (int i = 0; i < [arrayExample count]; ++i) {
        int r = (random() % [arrayExample count]);
        [arrayExample exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:r];
        NSLog(@"%@", [arrayExample description]);
    }
}
```

Here is my code

Comment: What problem are you having with the code you posted? Your question is unclear.

Comment: I want to show the array element in the NSLog

Comment: OK, so where's your attempt to log a single element from the array? Again, what issue are you having?

Comment: Its at the end of the for loop. Its just exiting out of the app with a break point

Comment: If your app is crashing (which you failed to mention) then you need to update your question with details about the crash including the full error message.

Comment: There is no error message, it just exists the app and goes to a break point at the NSLog

Comment: See http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: Do not use `random()`, it is not random. Instead use `arc4random()` or `arc4random_uniform()`. In this case: `arc4random_uniform([arrayExample count])`' This does not solve the question but is necessary for random operation.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain all relevant information. What problem are you having? What do the logs say?

Comment: Just to add on to what @Zaph commented, you can checkout Matt Thompson's article regarding random functions - http://nshipster.com/random/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this routine help you.

```
- (NSMutableArray *)generateRandomNumbers:(NSNumber *)numberOfElements {
    NSMutableArray *arrayRandomPositions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // First create sequential numbers array
    for (int i=0; i<[numberOfElements integerValue]; i = i +1) {
        [arrayRandomPositions addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
    }

    // Make the shuffle 
    for (int i = 0; i < [numberOfElements integerValue]; ++i) {
        // Select a random element between i and end of array to swap with.
        int nElements = (int)[numberOfElements integerValue] - i;
        int n = arc4random_uniform(nElements) + i;
        [arrayRandomPositions exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n];
    }

    return arrayRandomPositions;
}
```

Comment: There might be something wrong with the method name because it comes up with errors

Comment: You must call  something like this: NSMutableArray *positionCardsGame = [self getRandomNumbers:[NSNumber numberWithInt:8]];

Comment: I use this routine actually in some of my apps.

Comment: its wanting a ; after the (NSMutableArray *)

Comment: How do I apply this to a button and print it in NSLog?

Comment: It sounds like there's something wrong with the syntax of the code before the place where you inserted this method.

Comment: @Edward Heath maybe write something like this? NSLog(@"%@", [arrayExample objectAtIndex:i])

Comment: The complexity of the code is increased substantially by passing in `numberOfElements` as an `NSNumber` instead of just an `int`.

Comment: @Zaph you are correct. I use it for a short arrays and works very well.